# Node throws TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

Not certain, but think I have something that SHOULD work, but it doesn't, and the error I get is quite unhelpful.

So, trying to send the passport object to one of the routes, which I understand should be just to set

```
var users = require('./routes/users')(app, passport);
```

Which throws a fault on startup

```
> /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.0/bin/node app.js Test
> something 2
> /Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/goMinute/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:130
> var search = 1 + req.url.indexOf('?');
>                           ^ TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
>     at Function.proto.handle (/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/goMinute/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:130:27)
>     at router (/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/goMinute/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:35:12)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/goMinute/app.js:41:38)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
>     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
>     at startup (node.js:129:16)
>     at node.js:814:3
> 
> Process finished with exit code 1
```

If I remove app and passport, the problem disappears magically. the routs in ./routes/users does not use any of them yet.

I have added some of the code (removed a bit of passport configuration for good form)

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var methodOverride = require('method-override'); // simulate DELETE and PUT (express4)
var stylus = require('stylus');
var nib = require('nib');
var morgan = require('morgan');

//  express session and passport
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash    = require('connect-flash');




var app = express();
function compile(str, path) {
    return stylus(str)
        .set('filename', path)
        .use(nib())
}

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
var accesslevels = require('./config/accesslevels.js');
console.log("Test something " + accesslevels.userRoles.user);
// required for passport
app.use(session({ secret: '' + 'asifIwouldtellstackoverflowright', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true })); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session

//Routes after passports
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users')(app, passport);
var loginsrv = require('./routes/login');
var api = require('./routes/api');
var partials = require('./routes/partials');

var auth = function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.isAuthenticated())
        res.send(401);
    else
        next();
    };
//See more at: https://vickev.com/#!/article/authentication-in-single-page-applications-node-js-passportjs-angularjs

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // get information from html forms
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/partials', partials);
app.use('/loginsrv', loginsrv);

//app.use(accesslevels());

//console.log(accesslevels);
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
app.listen(30010);
```

EDIT: Added routes/users.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

/*
// route to test if the user is logged in or not
router.get('/loggedin', function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.isAuthenticated() ? req.user : '0');
});

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.user);
});

router.post('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.logOut();
    res.send(200);
});
*/

module.exports = router;
```

In the above code I have changed the original `router.get('/', function(req, res, next)` with     `router.get('/', function(app, passport, req, res, next)` which resolves the problem.

Comment: What is the scope of `req`?

Comment: What does `./routes/users.js` contain?

Comment: mscdex, nothing, have some code I was planning to run, but it is all commented out at the moment (as it needs the passport object configured in the main node part).

Comment: PM, as far as I know the scope of `require` would be global, think it is part of node.js it self (could be wrong though), I am fairly certain I do not change it from default.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case, if you have any HTTP verb routes app.get('/' ...) been used after app.use(..) then you will get this error in Express4x.

Ref [here](https://github.com/strongloop/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x#approuter)

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain I understand why, but the trick was to changed the original `router.get('/', function(req, res, next)` with     `router.get('/', function(app, passport, req, res, next)` which resolves the problem. Not certain why express requires a function that does not use the passed object to have passport and app, but it does it seems.

```
var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();

    /* GET users listing. */
    router.get('/', function(app,passport, req, res, next) {
      res.send('respond with a resource');
    });

    /*
    // route to test if the user is logged in or not
    router.get('/loggedin', function(req, res) {
        res.send(req.isAuthenticated() ? req.user : '0');
    });

    router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
        res.send(req.user);
    });

    router.post('/logout', function(req, res){
        req.logOut();
        res.send(200);
    });
    */

    module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/api',function(req,res)
{
    if (req.url.indexOf('/api')==0) {
        console.log('yes i have done it');
    }
});
```

i Have implemented this ,I m getting output on the console.What is Happening in your code is that req is undefined.So node is throwing this error...As you can see in my code we can only only use req.url.indexOf method only when we are in scope of req.(i.e    you must declare search inside function callback which handle req,res.....  )

Comment: Thank you very much Harpreet Singh, having a bit of a problem understanding why. I understand that req is not available, what I can't understand is why and where it is not available. I.e. I send two objects to the router, app and passport. when they end up in the router, req is not available. What I can't understand is, why is it no longer available, or why is it called only when I send those objects, I have not changes the actual route, the route works if I don't send the objects? (Also, where should I put the above code, put it just before the actual routes and that did not work.)

Comment: in that file have you created router object using app object.?if not do it like this '=

Comment: sorry for wrong comment above                                                                                    var router = app.Router();                                                                                         then declare the the route you want to implement  using router.get('/abc',function(req,res){ var search =req.url.indexOf('?');) or router.post('/abc',function(req,res){ var search =req.url.indexOf('?'); })

Comment: I am trying to sort out routes/users.js (added it to the question above). So far I am actually not calling app at all, the issue occurs as soon as I try to pass the object. If I do not pass the object (i.e. `var users = require('./routes/users');` rather than `var users = require('./routes/users')(app, passport); ` everything works. (Currently all the functions in the users router that will be using app and passport are commented out). So it seems like it is the act of passing the object using require that is causing express to report `^ TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`

Comment: I solved this by changing the request from 'get' to 'post', sending an empty body. For some reason, in router, the function as a second parameter of get request was not fired. To be more clear: router.get('/api/route', thisIsNotFired()). On post request it is fired. Sorry for lack of terms etc., I am not very experienced with node/express. Can someone direct me to the right resources for this subject?